# Contact and Friends using same Applications through facebook in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

Lets say I have an application on android and two of my friends have downloaded it.  Many apps such as words with friends have the ability to look at your friends, find out who has downloaded the same app and display it in your own application so you can play/challenge them now does anyone know a good starting point at what to look at to accomplish this goal of finding which of my friends are using my app through facebook or what can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query `me` endpoint as following

```
/me/friends?fields=id,installed,name
```

It will return friends of user with either `installed` feed set or not depending upon the condition if they have installed or not.

Further documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)